# Essential Prime Implicant

Tags: digital-logic

[image]

While solving this question using Quine–McCluskey algorithm , I am getting total EPIs as 3 but by definition , it is giving 2 EPIs. I am attaching both solutions. Please correct me where I am wrong.
[image]

[image]

Comment: There are lots of ways to cover the inner 2x2 grid...  the upper left and lower right 2x1 grids can't be covered except by themselves... the don't cares make it possible to cover the inner 1's in more than one way, as shown.

Comment: @vicatcu , Thanks. So, What should be the answer of this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prime implicant is only essential if no other prime implicants can 'cover' its outputs. As you pointed out, the only prime implicants that fit this definition are the ones in the corners. The ones in the middle can be covered both by the square and by the two horizontal rectangles. So the answer is two.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell why Quine–McCluskey algorithm is giving wrong answer ?

Comment: You missed m(11, 15) in the table.

Comment: yes sir , I have missed m(11,15) and m(13,15). Thank you so much.